# Is it possible to dynamically load a correct-sized image in this circumstance?

Tags: php, css

I have three divs that display in a row, collectively filling 100% width. Each div contains an image and some text beneath the image.

If the browser isn't wide enough to display the row of three, the last div moves beneath the first two and becomes much larger in width, so that the two divs, and the div that's now beneath them still fill 100% width.

The images displayed in the div exist in two different sizes (in folders called /thumbs and /largephotos).

Initially I was loading all the images from /thumbs, but if the third div drops to a second row, becoming larger, the image obviously pixelates. Therefore, for the third div, I pulled the image from the /largephotos folder, just in case it happened to be displayed large.

This is obviously slowing the page down unnecessarily in a lot of cases. I'd like to be able to show the correctly sized image each time.

The images are being retrieved from a database in a loop that repeats three times (it retrieves the most recent 3 images). I've tried various things with CSS media width but can't seem to find a solution.

```
    .wrapper {
        padding: 0px;
        max-width: 960px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .columns {
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: center;
        margin: 0px 0;
    }
    .column {
        flex: 1;
        border: 0px solid gray;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    ...........
    echo "<div class=\"wrapper\">";
    echo "<section class=\"columns\">";
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
        echo "<div class=\"column\"";
        ......
        if ($PhotosDisplayed < 2) {
           echo "<img class=\"featuredimage\" src=\"thumbs/";
          }
        else {
          echo "<img class=\"featuredimage\" src=\"largephotos/";
          }
        echo $row['Filename'];
        echo ".jpg\" ";
        ......
        $PhotosDisplayed++;
    }
```

The above code works perfectly, but it always loads the large photo for the third div (because $PhotosDisplayed=3). But I want to show the small photo if the browser is wide enough for the three divs to be in one row.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: Thank you very much!  SRCSET was completely new to me. It was the perfect solution :)